# Character's mesh distorts in illogical ways

Tags: modeling

I have now used the extrude command successfully a number of times, yet I am still very much a noob.  Yet, when I tried to extrude the stomach to give my character some paunch, the mesh seems to distort in an illogical way.  I can not get it to extend the belly area. The mesh is not assigned to anything, as i have not gotten that far yet.  Any help you can offer would be greatly appreciated!  I am uploading the file.

[image]

Comment: yes I am in edit mode, and when I select the vertex in the center of the stomach and hit E, the back side flairs out and the stomach drops down.  If   I extrude the stomach out, the backside is more distorted that the stomach.

Comment: you seem to be using the skin modifier, try selecting those vertices and hit mark/clear  loose

Comment: Hello again!  I appreciate you taking the time to answer my questions!  I tried selecting the vertex in the center of the stomach then I hit "mark loose", then "clear loose", then E to extrude.  As soon as I hit "E" the mesh distorted into that strange diagonal.  Also, I noted that my red circle that marks the root is very large.  Could that have something to do with it?

Comment: I was also only able to extrude along a diagonal when I was doing the character feet.  I posted a question and found out how to flatten them but never found out why I was only able to extrude along a diagonal.  I suspect the two are related.

Comment: the red circle size depended on the radius root you have set, if you are facing weird problems try installing new version or move the file on another system and try it, it could be a bug ?